# How do you solve variable height progressive reveal slider?

Tags: sliders

Say even on Google, you're first entering email, then pressing next, and the content of the little window is sliding leftwards to go to the next step, however the height changes and this makes the box jump. I don't think it's a very nice experience aesthetically. Maybe some height transition would be of place, but somebody at Google was lazy? This happens in other cases such as calendars, and sometimes people add an empty raw at the bottom of the calendar to account for variation between 4-6 weeks which is not very nice also because there's extra whitespace when not needed.

[image: progressive reveal]

Answer (score 0):

This almost certainly is a bug; the passkey infobox wasn't there when this thing was designed. I wouldn't use "lazy" here but rather "oversight".

Changing height with a transition animation definitely would be called for here, under the conditions that

1. it actually feels better
2. it is supported in all browsers/devices you intend to support. The login functionality is critical and having it not work because the animation breaks it is unacceptable.